# Javascript Object - Property Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Here's another code-snippet,

```
var jane = new Engineer("Doe, Jane", ["navigator", "javascript"], "belau");
```

I found it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

I apologize my bad. What does the part ["navigator", "javascript"] mean in the above line? Why are they written so? I've seen this in Facebook's JavaScript files as well.

But I cannot understand this, is it an object property array?

EDIT: I found this explanation,

> The constructor calls the base method, passing as its arguments two of
>   the arguments passed to the constructor ("Doe, Jane" and ["navigator",
>   "javascript"]) and also the string "engineering". Explicitly using
>   "engineering" in the constructor indicates that all Engineer objects
>   have the same value for the inherited dept property, and this value
>   overrides the value inherited from Employee.

Comment: you mean `$(".Arbiter, .ArbiterMixin, .Bootloader, .CSS, .DataStore, .DOM, .Event")` ? or what?

Comment: No, not with the $() that's when you want to tell jQuery which selectors to monitor for whatever you want to achieve, what I am out to understand is the part in my question above.

Comment: Its not fully clear what you want, do you want to assign all these classes to an element or do you want to iterate over all these classes and get the elements which have them assigned?

Comment: are you trying to make an array that contains the name of your classes? If yes, why do you think its not possible ?

Comment: @op i dont understand your question... explain in words what **exactly** you want to achieve

Comment: Yes, I upvote Banana and Mivaweb and add on: Describe what you want. Your question is not clear. I'd say your code line is possible... seems like valid javascript so far. What do you want?

Comment: @op please rephrase your question. as it is now, the answer is: **Is the above possible?** - yes. **how does one then utilize each of these** - simply, `classes [0], classes[1],` etc.

Comment: After your edit it is still not clear, those are 2 different things you mention

Comment: @N000b101, please explain **in words** what you are trying to achieve. your question is bound to be put on hold otherwise.

Comment: Now you have a complete new question???? Not good for my brain!

Comment: @Banana I am just trying to understand the code-snippet, I'd be happy if someone can explain this to me.

Comment: @N000b101 this is simply an array passed as a function argument, nothing special about it...it is the same as doing `var banana= ["stack","overflow"];  processJob(banana);`

Comment: @Banana How sure are you that it is as basic as that?

Comment: @N000b101 very sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`["navigator", "javascript"]` is the [array literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Array_literals). It can be used anywhere that a value is expected. For example:

- Assigning to a variable: `var x = [1,2]`
- Passing into a function call: `JSON.stringify(['a', 'b'])`
- Calling methods on it directly: `[1,2,3].forEach(function(val){console.log(val)});`

In your example

```
// The second argument passed to the Engineer constructor is an array with 
// two values: "navigator" and "engineer"
var jane = new Engineer("Doe, Jane", ["navigator", "javascript"], "belau");
```